# OpenERP Migration to Centos 6.5

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, centos6, openerp-7

I have problem when i migrate my OpenERP addons to centos 6.5, 
Previously the addons runs well in Ubuntu 12.04 and Debian 7
But for now I have an error like this:

```
2014-03-06 03:28:35,223 21557 ERROR bac-erp openerp.tools.safe_eval: Cannot eval '#\r\n{\r\n    \'name\'          : \'Project Task Detail\',\r\n    \'category\'      : \'Project Task Detail\',\r\n    \'version\'       : \'1.0\',\r\n    \'depends\'       : ["base","project"],\r\n    \'author\'        : \'Cahyo Bagus L\',\r\n    \'description\'   : \'\'\'Project Task Detail\'\'\',\r\n    \'init_xml\'      : [],\r\n    \'update_xml\'    : [\'bac_project_task_detail_view.xml\'],\r\n    \'installable\'   : True,\r\n    \'active\'        : False,\r\n}\r\n'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20140226_002804-py2.6.egg/openerp/tools/safe_eval.py", line 241, in safe_eval
    return eval(test_expr(expr, _SAFE_OPCODES, mode=mode), globals_dict, locals_dict)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20140226_002804-py2.6.egg/openerp/tools/safe_eval.py", line 107, in test_expr
    code_obj = compile(expr, "", mode)
  File "<string>", line 2
     {
^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
2014-03-06 03:28:35,224 21557 ERROR bac-erp openerp.netsvc: invalid syntax
('', 2, 2, '{\r\n')

    2014-03-06 02:14:20,121 21145 ERROR bac-erp openerp.netsvc: invalid syntax
    ('', 2, 1, '\r\n')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20140226_002804-py2.6.egg/openerp/netsvc.py", line 292, in dispatch_rpc
        result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20140226_002804-py2.6.egg/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 433, in dispatch
        return fn(*params)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20140226_002804-py2.6.egg/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 444, in exp_authenticate
        res_users = pooler.get_pool(db).get('res.users')
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20140226_002804-py2.6.egg/openerp/pooler.py", line 49, in get_pool
        return get_db_and_pool(db_name, force_demo, status, update_module)[1]
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20140226_002804-py2.6.egg/openerp/pooler.py", line 33, in get_db_and_pool
        registry = RegistryManager.get(db_name, force_demo, status, update_module)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20140226_002804-py2.6.egg/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 203, in get
        update_module)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20140226_002804-py2.6.egg/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 233, in new
        openerp.modules.load_modules(registry.db, force_demo, status, update_module)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20140226_002804-py2.6.egg/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 350, in load_modules
        force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20140226_002804-py2.6.egg/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 254, in load_marked_modules
        graph.add_modules(cr, module_list, force)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20140226_002804-py2.6.egg/openerp/modules/graph.py", line 102, in add_modules
        info = openerp.modules.module.load_information_from_description_file(module)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20140226_002804-py2.6.egg/openerp/modules/module.py", line 344, in load_information_from_description_file
        info.update(eval(f.read()))
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20140226_002804-py2.6.egg/openerp/tools/safe_eval.py", line 241, in safe_eval
        return eval(test_expr(expr, _SAFE_OPCODES, mode=mode), globals_dict, locals_dict)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20140226_002804-py2.6.egg/openerp/tools/safe_eval.py", line 107, in test_expr
        code_obj = compile(expr, "", mode)
      File "<string>", line 2

        ^
     SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is the Detail spec of my server.
Python 2.6
Centos 6.5
openerp-7 latest form nightly build. 
This Error happen only to custom addons i made, not addons included in openerp like hr,sale,purchase.
and here is my addons.

```
#__openerp__.py
    {
        'name'          : 'Project Task Detail',
        'category'      : 'Project Task Detail',
        'version'       : '1.0',
        'depends'       : ["base","project"],
        'author'        : 'Author Name',
        'description'   : '''Project Task Detail''',
        'init_xml'      : [],
        'update_xml'    : ['bac_project_task_detail_view.xml'],
        'installable'   : True,
        'active'        : False,
    }
```

Do you know why this happen? and what solution i can do to fix the problem? Please advice.
Thanks Before.

Comment: enter some module description and try again

Comment: Hi I do that and still get error. Do you have any idea?

Comment: here you are using 7.0, so remove 'init_xml' and 'update_xml'. use  'data'  instead of 'update_xml' as these are replaced in latest version. and try again. hope this will help you

Comment: Hi Mansi thank you for your answer i already do that but not luck.

Comment: Hi All, the problem was line endings encoding in windows format.
So after i change it to unix the problem disappear.
How to change it? go to your text editor or ide and find line endings.
I use sublime text 3. Go to menu View->line endings->Unix.